# Email addresses for research assistants

Tags: email, research-assistantship

What is the best email address for a Research Assistant (RA)?

I noticed that most of the RAs and faculty in grad schools use their first name only as an email handle, like: `firstname@school.edu`.

However, as far as I know, the "perfect" professional email address would be like: `FirstnameLastname@school.edu`.

Only few of them used this format but with a dot in the middle, like: `Firstname.Lastname@school.edu`.

I think it might be neater to use the firstname-only form, but is it still professional to use it?

I'm sorry for this silly question, but I would appreciate your clarification.

Comment: Surely this is entirely dependent on your institution's policy for assigning email addresses? Other than at very small institutions, the chance that you have any choice in the matter at all is minimal...

Comment: This is probably going to get closed for inviting too many opinions. There's no definitive answer, and I don't even agree that *most* RAs choose the `first@school.edu` format. That would have been already taken at my university. I had 'bbarth@labname.school.edu' because we ran our own mail back then.

Comment: I like firstname@glastname.com, so that it stays the same whichever institution I happen to work for or study at.

Comment: @Gaurav: what does the "g" stand for?

Comment: @Taladris it's my first initial, but I didn't want to write down "first@(first initial)last.com", so I went for the simpler option and hoped people would think it was a typo. Alas, no :-P

Comment: I'm not really sure why this is closed as "opinion-based" --- it seems pretty straightforward to me.

Answer (score 13):

Most schools don't actually give you a choice: they simply set you up with a standard email address following their standard format.  Often this is some combination of first name or first initial plus last name, though I've even seen some schools give everybody a horrible alphanumerical mess as their official email address.  Many places will then also give you an option of setting up one or more email aliases, which you can use to modify the default.

Personally, I think that anything that includes your last name (and nothing else bizarre) is pretty reasonable and professional.  For my own case, for example, one can reach me in various locations with various forms of "beal", "jbeal", "jakebeal", "jacobbeal", and "jacob.beal", all of which convey the same basic information of "yes, this is who you think it is."

It is worth noting that, in some circles, being the one to get your first name or your initials on a system can be considered particularly special.  This is because it can indicate that you had been a very early adopter and/or involved in the system's development.  That's unlikely to be the case for most RAs at a university, however.

Answer (score 0):

In a small group, particularly one you are starting, you *might* be able to set policy by selecting your email. Otherwise, you are probably stuck with whatever local policy dictates. At LSU when starting my PhD I was asked for my preferred Unix login, I gave my surname (exactly 8 letters ;-). Here in Chile middle names aren't commonly used, so we used first initial + (at most) 7 letters of the surname; if that gave a collision, use middle initial to disambiguate; if still colliding, apply some special rule. The university policy is first.last, decorated by numbers (2, 3, ...) in case of repeats. At least at the Computer Lab of Cambridge in the UK the policy seems to be three initials plus a number.

Comment: Cambridge has used abc123 across all departments since more or less day one, I believe, and it's assigned sequentially. They're into (or close to?)  four digits for some of the most common two-letter pairs.